# Диаграммы архитектуры системы

Tags: uml

Какие диаграммы помогут изобразить архитектуру системы? Я видел примеры из блоков с блоками внутри и стрелками между блоками.

Comment: @Alex9, Постарайтесь писать более развернутые вопросы. Поясните, в чем вы видите проблему, какие  инструменты вы уже пробовали, какие недостатки видите и т. д.

Comment: Я имею в виду вот это http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3926629/figure/f3-sensors-14-01629/. Где посмотреть о том, как построить такую же диаграмму, но для своей программы?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Диаграмма компонентов](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%94%D0%B8%D0%B0%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B0_%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2)

[Диаграмма классов (class diagram)](http://habrahabr.ru/post/74330/)